# Reactjs doesen't re render after setState to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I finish to get data from my database and I useState setValue and pass the array, render function doesen't render again.

Code where I setArray

```
function getNotifiche(){
     onSnapshot(collection(db, "Users",auth.currentUser.uid, "Notifiche"), async (snapNotifiche) => {
            const notifichee = [];
            snapNotifiche.forEach(async notificaDoc => {

                const docRef = doc(db,"Users",notificaDoc.data().Invitato);
                const userData = await getDoc(docRef);

                
                        notifichee.push({
                            "data":notificaDoc.data(),
                            "invitante":userData.data()
                            })
               });
          
            setListaNotifiche(notifichee);

});
```

This is in the return function:

```
 {         
        (listaNotifiche.map((notifica,index)=>{
            return(<div key={index}>
                <label>Invitato da {notifica.invitante.Username} in data{new Date(notifica.data.DataInvito.seconds * 1000).toString()}</label>
                <button>Partecipa</button>
                <button>Elimina</button> 
                </div>);
        }))
    }
```

So I tried also using setListaNotifiche([...notifichee]) but I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: What debugging have you done to confirm that the state isn't being updated?  And that the error isn't occurring *before* the state is updated at all?  When is `getNotifiche` ever invoked?  What is the value of the state before that?  What is the initial state?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @David I've console log the array and when it was full I saw nothing displayed. In the first version of the code I pushed only the notificheDoc.data() in the array and it worked now that the array is made of objects the render doesen't get updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` doesn't know anything about promises or async functions. By the time the `.forEach` finishes, `notifichee` is still an empty array, and then you set state with an empty array. Some time later the array will be mutated to have data, but that comes after the component is rendered.

Instead, you will need to wait for the promises to finish before creating the array and setting state. You can use `.map` to create an array of promises, then `Promise.all` to combine them into a single promise, and then await that promise to get the array of data:

```
onSnapshot(
  collection(db, "Users", auth.currentUser.uid, "Notifiche"),
  async (snapNotifiche) => {
    const promises = snapNotifiche.docs.map(async (notificaDoc) => {
      const docRef = doc(db, "Users", notificaDoc.data().Invitato);
      const userData = await getDoc(docRef);
      return {
        data: notificaDoc.data(),
        invitante: userData.data(),
      }
    })
    const notifichee = await Promise.all(promises);

    setListaNotifiche(notifichee);
  }
);
```

Comment: I get that snapNotifiche.map is not a function

Comment: Sorry, should be `snapNotifiche.docs.map`